# I want to pass a variable from vuejs tospring boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vue.js, spring-mvc, backend

In below code front end by vue.js on local host 8080, so when clicking on button "r1" the postpost method work to send "calcoperation" variable to spring boot on local host 8085.

```
  <div class="home">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    
    <h2>You can enter the operation by buttons or by keyboard</h2>
    
    <input type="text" v-model="calcoperation" id="calculationid"  >
    <br>

    <button class="r1" v-on:click="postPost()">=</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default{
  name:"home",
  
  data(){
    return{
    
      title: "",
      
      calcoperation: "" ,
      errors: []
    };
  },

  mounted(){ //from spring boot to vue
    fetch("http://localhost:8085")
      .then(response =>{
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(data =>{
        this.title=data;
      });
      
  },

postPost() {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8085`, {
      body: this.calcoperation
    })  
 } 
}
</script>
```

Then i want to request that post and pass it calcvalue, but when i try to send calcvalue to title variable in vue and display it in "h1" it did not work.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class homecontroller {
    String calcvalue;

    @RequestMapping(value = "http://localhost:8080")
    void getcalcoperation(@RequestParam String calc) {
        calcvalue = calc ;
    }

    @GetMapping("/") // from spring boot to vue
    public String home() {
        return calcvalue;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two endpoints with the same path and method. I think the default for the request mapping is a get, if one is get and the other is post then you need to specify it, or if you plan to use two rest endpoints with the same method you need to make them point to different paths.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
void getcalcoperation(@RequestParam String calc) {
    calcvalue = calc ;
}

@GetMapping("/") // from spring boot to vue
public String home() {
    return calcvalue;
}
```

Also, you are using two different APIs for the call to the back-end (fetch and axios) an advice would be to use only one, even though this doesn't give you any problems.

Comment: @Dharman , sorry i tried it , but it did not work, as variable "calcvalue" in spring boot did not recieve the data from vue.js , and then send it again to variable "title" in vue.js .

Comment: @OmarAshraf Please stop pinging me. I am not the author of this answer. I didn't write it.

Comment: @OmarAshraf the front-end seems to fetch first the get mapping and after posting the value to the back-end. To test this out, try to give a default value to the back-end variable calcvalue and see if is displayed properly in the front end. The mounted is triggered as soon as the page render.

Comment: @OmarAshraf also what they said below need to be done.

Comment: I did what you said and below also, when i gave it a default value it works and this value is displayed , but postPost seems not working also. @PaoloA.

Comment: @OmarAshraf, please add an EDITED section to your question with the updated code so that we can see what changed. Then extract the mounted fetch in it's own method and then in the mounted section you call that function. After this, on the axios.post() you a .then(() => fetchTitle()). Doing so you are updating the value and then requesting it again.

Answer (score 1):

The `postPost()` method must be inside methods object like this

```
methods:{
  postPost() {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8085`, {
      body: this.calcoperation
    });
  }
}
```

And the mounted method will not be invoked automatically.
You might need to put that also into methods and call it manually to set the data into `title` data property. You may use a callback to achieve it.

Comment: Also in the template section, replace the "postPost()" by "postPost"   

<button class="r1" v-on:click="postPost">=</button>